# How does 'find -exec' pass file names with spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, find, quoting, arguments

If I have a directory containing some files whose names have spaces, e.g.

```
$ ls -1 dir1
file 1
file 2
file 3
```

I can successfully copy all of them to another directory like this:

```
$ find dir1 -mindepth 1 -exec cp -t dir2 {} +
```

However, the output of `find dir1 -mindepth 1` contains un-escaped spaces:

```
$ find dir1 mindepth 1
dir1/file 1
dir1/file 3
dir1/file 3
```

If I use `print0` instead of `print`, the output still contains un-escaped spaces:

```
$ find dir1 mindepth 1 -print0
dir1/file 1dir1/file 2dir1/file 3
```

To copy these files manually using `cp`, I would need to escape the spaces; but it seems that this is unnecessary when `cp`'s aguments come from `find`, irrespective of whether I use `+` or `\;` at the end of the command.

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `find` command executes the command directly.  The command, including the filename argument, will not be processed by the shell or anything else that might modify the filename.  It's very safe.

You are correct that there's no need to escape filenames which are represented by `{}` on the `find` command line.

`find` passes the raw filename from disk directly into the internal argument list of the `-exec` command, in your case, the `cp` command.

Comment: In a nutshell, `find..exec` can handle weird filenames on its own..

Comment: The first rule of linux club is you do not parse ls

Comment: what's the relevance of parsing ls here if I might?

Comment: @MrR I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps it's in reference to "passes the raw filename from disk directly into the internal argument list"

Comment: What do you do if you need a pipe in your exec command? The accepted answer on this site is to `find . -exec sh -c "echo {} | wc -c" \;` (as an example). But it seems to me like using exec this way doesn't follow the rules of this answer.

Comment: @DanielKaplan I don't know what you mean by "the accepted answer on this site" and "the rules of this answer."  That snippet is an expensive way to count the characters in filenames.  It's very inefficient because of calling `wc` on each filename found. It's also dangerous because the `{}` could expand to characters which have meaning to the shell such as `{}|;():#` etc.

Comment: Ha! Thanks for taking the time to reply. I think I was extremely tired when I wrote that. Now that I'm alert... TL;DR: **Does your answer apply when you want to use a pipe in an `-exec` string?** In detail: By "accepted answer," I meant the highest voted answer for how to pipe commands in an `-exec`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/307154/61624 By "the rules of this answer," I meant, if I'd like to pipe commands in an `-exec`, it doesn't seem like I can use your answer: compared to `-exec`ing a single command, piping commands in `-exec` seems like an entirely different beast.

Comment: I've decided to create a standalone question for this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700643/how-do-i-deal-with-strange-file-name-characters-when-piping-find-output

Answer (score 9):

The question is two-part:

- how *does* `find` manage to call programs using `-exec` without running into problems with spaces embedded in filenames, and
- what good is the `-print0` option?

For the first, `find` is making a system call, actually one of a group of related calls referred to as ["exec"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec). It passes the filename as an argument directly to this call, which then is passed directly (after creating a new process) without losing information about the filename.

The POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) feature `+` is explained as follows, in the [rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_18):

> A feature of SVR4's `find` utility was the `-exec` primary's +
>   terminator. This allowed filenames containing special characters
>   (especially *newline* characters) to be grouped together without the
>   problems that occur if such filenames are piped to `xargs`. Other
>   implementations have added other ways to get around this problem,
>   notably a `-print0` primary that wrote filenames with a null byte
>   terminator. This was considered here, but not adopted. Using a null
>   terminator meant that any utility that was going to process find's
>   `-print0` output had to add a new option to parse the null terminators
>   it would now be reading.

That "***notably*** a `-print0` primary" refers to GNU `find` and `xargs` which solve the problem in a different way.  It is also supported by FreeBSD [`find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and [`xargs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).  If you added a `-0` option (see the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)) to the `xargs` call, then that program accepts lines terminated by "null byte" characters.  In turn, `xargs` calls *exec*-functions to do *its* work.  The main distinction between the `-print0` and `-0` feature versus the `+` feature is that the former passes the filenames over a pipe, while the latter does not.  Developers find uses for almost any feature; the pipes are no exception.

Back to OP's example, which uses a `-t` option to `cp`: that is not found in [POSIX cp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html).  Rather, it is an extension (aka "nonstandard feature") provided by [GNU cp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html).  The `-0` extension of `xargs` would not improve this example, but there are other cases where it can be used effectively—keeping in mind that there is the portable alternative `+`, which GNU `find` accepts.

Answer (score 0):

(*This should be a comment but it's too large.*)

For those who like to try things out:

Create a script listing positional parameters passed in, call it `list_positional_parameters.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html
# Try globbing patterns, e.g. "X[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]" to see what happens

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 and then at least one parameter"
   exit 1
fi

counter=1

while (($#)); do
   echo "$counter = '$1'"
   # pop positional argument 1 off the stack of positional arguments
   shift
   (( counter++ ))
done
```

Run `find` with it on some directory $dir:

```
find "$dir" -exec ./list_positional_parameters.sh '{}' ';' | less
```

As expected, there is only a single parameter in all calls, the filename, whether there are spaces in its name or not.

Comment: You may also use `printf` like `printf '"%s"\n' "$@"` to print out all positional argument quoted, for visual inspection.