# Bash script to count file types in a path (including subfolders)

Tags: bash, find, file-types

I would like to get a quick overview over the different file types in a directory (including all its subdirectories) using the `file` tool, e.g. telling me what file type is the most common one there.

It should be implemented as a practical shell script in common shell languages or scripting tools like `bash` or `awk`.

Possible nice-to-haves:

- good performance
- dealing with any file name or type
- POSIX compatibility

(last two points are practically mutually exclusive)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sort | uniq -c` to count identical lines:

```
find "$path" -type f -exec file -b {} + | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: Great, I love this solution! `uniq -c` is quite handy to know about.

Comment: why not `find $path -type f -exec file -b {} +` in place of `find .. | xargs`? `{} +` is in POSIX

Comment: @iroovar Thanks, that's simpler and just as fast.  Although `file -b` is still non-standard.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Isn't `file` generally non-standard?

Comment: @iroovar Does `-exec {} +` similarly protect against reaching `ARG_MAX` like `xargs` does?

Comment: @JigglyNaga Oh and you probably also want to put `$path` inside double-quotes.

Comment: @phk `file` has an Open Group spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html

Comment: @phk, [yes](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files)

Comment: You should enclose the ```{}``` portion of the command inside of single-quotes to properly deal with files/folders with spaces.  So use ```-exec file -b '{}' +```

Comment: @tgharold Are you sure about that?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243095/how-does-find-exec-pass-file-names-with-spaces

Answer (score 1):

Bash 4 solution utilizing associative integer arrays and for environments with the zero delimiter extensions. First parameter is the target directory, all following parameters are forwarded to `file`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# USAGE: script.sh PATH [PARAMS_FOR_FILE_CMD...]
# EXAMPLE 1: ./script.sh .
# EXAMPLE 2: ./script.sh /tmp --mime-type

path=$1
shift

if [[ ! -d "$path" ]]; then
  echo 'Path expected as first argument!' >&2
  echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") PATH [PARAMS_FOR_FILE_CMD...]" >&2
  exit 1
fi

declare -Ai type_stats

while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do

  t=$(file -b "$@" -- "$f")

  type_stats[$t]+=1

done < <(find "$path" -type f -print0)

for t in "${!type_stats[@]}"; do

  printf '\n%s\n-> %s\n\0' "$t" "${type_stats[$t]}"

done | sort -zrn -t'>' -k2
```

Performance should be OK and I guess it deals with all file names and types (not entirelly sure though, e.g. unless there is a type with '>' in it).

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old but, this is one of top results when searching for "bash count file extensions".

I encountered the same problem as you and created a script similar to JigglyNaga

Here is the command i made that counts the extensions of all files in the working directory and subfolders recursively. This takes into account UPPER, and LOWER cases, merging them, removing false positive results, and counting the occurrences.

`find . -type f | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

Here is the github link if you'd like to see more documentation.

https://github.com/Hoppi164/list_file_extensions

Comment: Strictly speaking this is just looking at file endings instead of really trying to find out the type of each file (which s why I asked for usage of the `file` tool in the original post). Nevertheless since there is normally a strong correlation between file name endings and their types your solution is probably OK for most cases. It could probably be simplified a lot though (e.g. those two `sort`s and `uniq` combined, `sed` and `grep` combined, no `-e` for `sed` necessary…).

Comment: Why are you including files like `.bashrc` or `file.` or `file.ŷŷŷ` but excluding those like `file.c++` or `file.zsh-theme` or `file.ẑẑẑ`?

Comment: Also note that it won't work properly if there are paths containing newline characters.

Comment: Note that `sed` is a superset of `grep`, you almost never need to pipe them together as `sed` can do most of `grep`'s job.

Comment: Also beware that in `sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/'`, in several `sed` implementations, the `.*` will only match valid characters in the current locale, so that  command will give the wrong result if there are file path encoded in a different charmap than the locale's. For instance, on a `$'./Chazelas/St\xe9phane/contact.csv'`, in a UTF-8 locale, GNU `sed` would yield `./Chazelas/St<e9>.csv` as `.` won't match on that `0xe9` byte which is the latin1 encoding of `é`, but invalid in UTF-8.